# Is it possible for the supervisor to pass the exception to the calling actor if the child actor fails even after retrying N times?

Tags: scala, akka

I have two actors Computer and Printer. Computer is the parent of Printer and has a one for one strategy defined for Printer.

I have listed the code below.

```
class Computer extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  import Computer._
  import Printer._

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 2 seconds

  val printer: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[Printer], "printer-actor")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Print(text) => {
      val printJob: Future[Any] = printer ? PrintJob(Random.nextInt, text)

      printJob.mapTo[Page].map {
        case Page(text) => {
          log.info(s"Received page containing text ${text}")
          context.system.shutdown()
        }
      }.onFailure {
        case t: Throwable => sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(t)
      }
    }
  }

  override val supervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 3, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
      case e : Exception => {
        log.info(s"caught exception of type ${e.getClass}")
        SupervisorStrategy.Restart
      }
    }
}

class Printer extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  import Printer._

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case PrintJob(id, text) => {
      log.info(s"Received ${PrintJob(id, text)}")
      if (Random.nextBoolean) sender ! Page(text)
      else throw new NoPaperException(id)
    }
  }


  override def preRestart(cause: Throwable, message: Option[Any]) = {
    log.info(s"Restarting actor ${self} because of ${cause}. Queueing message ${message}")
    postStop()
    message.map(self forward _)
  }
}
```

The Printer throws an exception based on the random generator. The code works fine, the supervisor restarts the and retries the child actor on failure just as instructed.

However the ask pattern `val printJob: Future[Any] = printer ? PrintJob(Random.nextInt, text)` fails with a AkkaTimeoutException in case all attempts to get the Printer actor work fails.

Is there a way to pass back the exact exception which caused the actor to fail ? In this case NoPapperException.

Cheers,

Utsav

Answer (score 0):

to pass the exception back to the sender you need to `sender ! Status.Failure(e)` - where e is the exception

You can either do that directly from the actor, or if you want to do that from the supervisor you need to have a subclass of exception that would hold the sender ref with it so that the supervisor would be able to send the exception back